# Error to connecting to my database (MySQL, C#)

Tags: c#, mysql

This did not worked when I ran the program!

```
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace MySQL
{
    class SqlConnection
    {
        public SqlConnection() { }
        ~SqlConnection() { }
        private string strConnection = "Server=localhost;Database=database;Port=3306;User ID=root;Password=";
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        public void OpenConnection()
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection();
            connection.Open();
        }
        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
        public string StrConnection
        {
            set
            {
                StrConnection = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return StrConnection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it is not working!

> ERROR : host 'xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB sever!

Answer (score 3):

You don't use the connection string property `strConnection`, when you initialize your connection. Try:

```
public void OpenConnection()
{
   connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
   connection.Open();
}
```